# Two buttons directing to the same New Form but need different content displayed Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two buttons on my Show page directing to my New Form which are: Single Request, Multiple Request. For the single request the current New Form is sufficient but what I haven't been able to figure out is if the Multiple Request button is clicked on the Show Page and sends the user to the New Form it should display the same content as the New Form does now only multiple times.

I was searching around for answer and even watched RailsCast#38 but both the answers I found and the video only pertained to multiple buttons on the Form itself not linking to the Form.

Thanks For the Help!

Comment: Could you please clarify this: `does now only multiple times.`. What does it  mean exactly?

Comment: Both Buttons direct the User to the New form. For Single Request the form can stay how it is but if Multiple Request is clicked then I need display the single request form multiple times.